# How do you fill in the area under a data series in a line chart in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, libreoffice

There is a line chart in an Excel spreadsheet that I'm trying to replicate in a native ODS spreadsheet. The chart has lines from multiple data series, and one of those lines has the area underneath it filled in. Is there any way to replicate this in Libre Office Calc? I can't see any options anywhere to add a filled-in area selectively to a data series' line in the chart. When I open the Excel sheet in Libre Office, I can see options to change the appearance of the filled-in area, so I assumed there would be an option somewhere to add a filled-in area in the first place.

Comment: Never used Libre, but it sounds like you're saying Libre doesn't offer a combo chart? That is, 3 series are line, and 4th series is area.

Comment: It doesn't look like combo charts are an option (the closest selection is the 'line and column' type, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

When viewed in Google Sheets, the chart type appears to be "Combo Chart". This type isn't available in Libre Office Calc, meaning it's not possible to replicate the chart (at least not without going through a lot of hassle).